# Loading and saving pfs file in Pylon

Tags: c#, computer-vision

I'm working with the Pylon SDK for basler cameras.
I need to save and load the camera settings (pfs file).
I could not find any resources in the sdk's or online.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if t late or not, but anyway you have to download [pylon SDK](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/sales-support/downloads/software-downloads/pylon-5-1-0-linux-x86-64-bit/) to work with Basler cameras, 
here is a c++ code which loads a .pfs file:

```
void Basler::loadNodeMap(const std::string& fileName) const throw (utility::Exception)
{
    Pylon::String_t _fileName = fileName.c_str();

    try {
        Pylon::CFeaturePersistence::Load(_fileName, &camera->GetNodeMap(), true);
    } catch (const Pylon::GenericException& exception) {
        throw utility::Exception(exception.GetDescription());
    }
}
```

and I usually use Pylon Viewer to adjust fetures and then save .pfs file.